# How do I edit the crontab for SpamAssassin updates on CentOS 6?

Tags: linux, centos, cron, spamassassin

I receive this email daily:

```
From: Cron Daemon
Subject: Cron <root@server> /usr/share/spamassassin/sa-update.cron 2>&1 | tee -a /var/log/sa-update.log

UTF-16 surrogate 0xd800 at /usr/local/share/perl5/Pod/Simple/BlackBox.pm line 67.
UTF-16 surrogate 0xd800 at /usr/local/share/perl5/Pod/Simple/BlackBox.pm line 67.
UTF-16 surrogate 0xd800 at /usr/local/share/perl5/Pod/Simple/BlackBox.pm line 67.
```

I tried to edit the crontab to remove the `tee` command and only append to the log file, however, I can't find the crontab.

```
# grep spam /etc/passwd
spam:x:510:511::/usr/local/spamassassin:/bin/false
# crontab -l -u spam
no crontab for spam
```

I also tried to list `root`'s crontab (`# crontab -l`), but it only had entries for backup and `certbot-auto`. I've already tried to update Perl (`yum update perl` and `cpanm Pod::Simple::BlackBox Mail::SpamAssassin`). How do I edit the crontab to avoid this daily error email?

CentOS release 6.10 (Final)

Answer (score 0):

I found and fixed it with

```
# grep -r sa-update.cron /etc/*
/etc/cron.d/sa-update:#10 4 * * * root /usr/share/spamassassin/sa-update.cron 2>&1 | tee -a /var/log/sa-update.log
/etc/cron.d/sa-update:10 4 * * * root /usr/share/spamassassin/sa-update.cron 2>&1 >> /var/log/sa-update.log
```